# Size of separate bounding boxes?

Tags: c++, opencv, codeblocks, bounding-box

I want to make a piece of software that detects all the objects in an image and deletes everything except for the biggest one. I got all the separate bounding boxes & contours drawn but how do I go about comparing the size of each different bounding box / contour to make out which one is the biggest?

Comment: Have you read this one http://answers.opencv.org/question/7171/calculating-the-area-of-bounding-box/

Comment: Biggest perimeter would be simplest to calculate

Comment: Good read @AurélienOoms thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your bounding boxes `CvRect` objects? Assuming "biggest" means largest area, you can do something like this.

```
std::vector<CvRect*> vBoundingBoxes;    // assume this has all your boxes
int largestArea = 0;
CvRect* pLargestBox = NULL;

for (auto it = vBoundingBoxes.begin(); it != vBoundingBoxes.end(); ++it)
{
    CvRect* pCurrentBox = *it;
    int iArea = pCurrentBox->width * pCurrentBox->length;
    if (iArea > largestArea)
    {
        largestArea = iArea;
        pLargestBox = pCurrentBox;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup they are of the type cv::rectangle. Ill give it a shot with that code. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Cyber I was looking at this code again and was wondering what 'pLargestBox & pCurrentBox acctually are. I mean are they some kind of variable? Because I dont see them being defined..

Comment: @TheAlPaca02 They are pointers to `CvRect` objects. I assumed that you had a vector of these objects in `vBoundingBoxes`. So I looped over that vector one at a time, and dereferenced the iterator `*it`, which contains the `CvRect` object. Are you familiar with pointers? If not, some of that may need further explanation.

Comment: Yeah Im familiar with pointers, its just that I've never seen a 'p' as prefix to declare them. Everyone around here uses an asterix haha. Thanks for clearing up my uncertainties tho!

Comment: @TheAlPaca02 Oh, that is called [Hungarian Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation), it is a widely accepted naming style. You start the variable name off with the first letter of the type like bFlag (bool), dAnswer (double), pThingy (pointer), etc.